# Редактирование HTML/CSS-кода на Wordpress+Elementor. Засада:(

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

Занимаюсь версткой сайтов.
Обратился ко мне заказчик с просьбой добавить анимации на страницу сайта Wordpress.
Я согласился. Все как бы ничего, но оказалось, что страница сделана на Элементоре.
Сложность в том, что в самой папке ВП я не могу найти эту страницу сайта, чтобы доработать ее на html/css.
Может кто-то сталкивался с подобными задачами? Где мне найти файл? Какие есть особенности при правке страниц на ВП+Элементор? Может, есть какие-то материалы в сети на эту тему? (искал, но пока что все не то).

Не хочу сразу давать заднюю перед заказчиком. Хочу разобраться в теме.

Comment: Не ломай себе психику, пускай заказчик ищет другого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elementor в WP правится через админку при редактировании страницы/записи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там Вам будут доступны различные элементы, которые Вы располагаете в области контента, настраиваете вывод, дизайн, всякие различные анимации там тоже есть. Правда я толком не помню, кажется они либо все, либо большинство из них, срабатывают при наведении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Уже разобрался. В нем даже есть встроенный редактор кода, но даже при его наличии анимации по моему заданию либо нереально сделать, либо надо пыхтеть в различных позах)) все-таки для других вещей создан Элементор)